# Snowflake InterfaceError: Failed to convert current row, cause: int too big to convert

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to built a utility script which pulls data from Snowflake into a dataframe within a local jupyter notebook. When I run it, I keep getting this error:

```
InterfaceError: (snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: int too big to convert
```

Can someone guide me what I am doing wrong here? Any help is highly appreciated.

Code:

```
def read_sql (path, file):
    """Reads SQL file from local env and returns query as string"""
    with open(os.path.join(path, file)) as sql_file:
        sql = sql_file.read()
    return sql

def db_con(sql,
          user,
          password,
          warehouse):
    """Setup db connection, runs query and returns pandas df"""
    
    
    engine = create_engine(
    URL(account='123,
       user,
       password,
       database,
       schema,
       warehouse,
       numpy=True,),
       poolclass=pool.StaticPool
    )
    
    try:
        connection = engine.connect()
        connection.execute('Use Warehouse {warehouse};'.format(warehouse=warehouse))
        df = pd.read_sql(sql,engine)
    finally:
        connection.close()
        engine.dispose()
    return df
```

When I call this function, I get that error:

```
#Get Data
sql = '''select * from "d1"."public"."some_table" limit 1 '''

df = db_con(sql, 
            USERNAME, 
            PASSWORD, 
            WAREHOUSE, 
            DATABASE)

df.head()

Error:
Initialize Query
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
    972         try:
--> 973             rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
    974             result._soft_close()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py in fetchall(self)
    990         while True:
--> 991             row = self.fetchone()
    992             if row is None:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py in fetchone(self)
    956         try:
--> 957             return next(self._result)
    958         except StopIteration:

src/snowflake/connector/arrow_result.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult.__next__()

src/snowflake/connector/arrow_iterator.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_iterator.PyArrowIterator.__next__()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in errorhandler_wrapper(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    257             cursor.messages.append((error_class, error_value))
--> 258             cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    259             return

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    187         """
--> 188         raise error_class(
    189             msg=error_value.get("msg"),

InterfaceError: 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: int too big to convert

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-48-373f7ee62b3f> in <module>
      2 sql = '''select * from "PRODUCTION"."SFDC"."CONTRACT" limit 1 '''
      3 
----> 4 df = db_con(sql, 
      5             USERNAME,
      6             PASSWORD,

<ipython-input-45-0f30a2664209> in db_con(sql, user, password, warehouse, database, schema)
     29         print('Initialize Query')
     30         connection.execute('Use Warehouse {warehouse};'.format(warehouse=warehouse))
---> 31         df = pd.read_sql(sql,engine)
     32     finally:
     33         connection.close()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    519         )
    520     else:
--> 521         return pandas_sql.read_query(
    522             sql,
    523             index_col=index_col,

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, parse_dates, params, chunksize)
   1319             )
   1320         else:
-> 1321             data = result.fetchall()
   1322             frame = _wrap_result(
   1323                 data,

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py in fetchall(self)
    996         """A synonym for the :meth:`_engine.Result.all` method."""
    997 
--> 998         return self._allrows()
    999 
   1000     def fetchone(self):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py in _allrows(self)
    406         make_row = self._row_getter
    407 
--> 408         rows = self._fetchall_impl()
    409         if make_row:
    410             made_rows = [make_row(row) for row in rows]

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/cursor.py in _fetchall_impl(self)
   1772 
   1773     def _fetchall_impl(self):
-> 1774         return self.cursor_strategy.fetchall(self, self.cursor)
   1775 
   1776     def _fetchmany_impl(self, size=None):

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
    975             return rows
    976         except BaseException as e:
--> 977             self.handle_exception(result, dbapi_cursor, e)
    978 
    979 

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/cursor.py in handle_exception(self, result, dbapi_cursor, err)
    935 
    936     def handle_exception(self, result, dbapi_cursor, err):
--> 937         result.connection._handle_dbapi_exception(
    938             err, None, None, dbapi_cursor, result.context
    939         )

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception(self, e, statement, parameters, cursor, context)
   1927                 util.raise_(newraise, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e)
   1928             elif should_wrap:
-> 1929                 util.raise_(
   1930                     sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   1931                 )

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    209 
    210         try:
--> 211             raise exception
    212         finally:
    213             # credit to

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/cursor.py in fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor)
    971     def fetchall(self, result, dbapi_cursor):
    972         try:
--> 973             rows = dbapi_cursor.fetchall()
    974             result._soft_close()
    975             return rows

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py in fetchall(self)
    989         ret = []
    990         while True:
--> 991             row = self.fetchone()
    992             if row is None:
    993                 break

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py in fetchone(self)
    955             self._prefetch_hook()
    956         try:
--> 957             return next(self._result)
    958         except StopIteration:
    959             return None

src/snowflake/connector/arrow_result.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult.__next__()

src/snowflake/connector/arrow_iterator.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_iterator.PyArrowIterator.__next__()

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in errorhandler_wrapper(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    256         if cursor is not None:
    257             cursor.messages.append((error_class, error_value))
--> 258             cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    259             return
    260         elif connection is not None:

/opt/anaconda3/envs/modeling/lib/python3.8/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    186             A Snowflake error.
    187         """
--> 188         raise error_class(
    189             msg=error_value.get("msg"),
    190             errno=error_value.get("errno"),

InterfaceError: (snowflake.connector.errors.InterfaceError) 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: int too big to convert
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Comment: Can you provide some information around the data you are selecting?  It seems like there is a value in the table that doesn't fit into the dataframe's integer definition.  Perhaps you have a varchar field in the database that is all numbers, and they are too long for integer??

Comment: @MikeWalton You were right. I just tested this with one random column in the select statement and it worked. There must be indeed some column(s) that are too big but I need to investigate further. For now, thanks for solving my issue.

Comment: This is most probably related to this [issue](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/277). This happens when your data stored is usually an INT64 data type while numpy uses default INT32.